# Double Tapping Key Press in Java

Tags: java, keylistener

I am making a Java game for my final project. I have my basic class Structure made. I want it to when I press escape it brings up a pause menu and if I press it again then it will exit the program. 
This is the code I have so far.

```
package Pong;

import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.util.*;

public class Pong implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{


public static Pong pong;

public int width = 1300, height = 750;
public RenderingClass renderer;

int balls;
int gameStart = 0;

public Paddles paddle1, paddle2;
public Ball ball1;

public boolean w, s, up, down;

public int time = 0;

public Pong()
{
    JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Extreme Pong: Final Game");

    Timer timer = new Timer(time, this);

    renderer = new RenderingClass();

    frame.setSize(width + 15, height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.add(renderer);

    start();

    timer.start();

}

public void start()
{
    paddle1 = new Paddles(this, 1);
    paddle2 = new Paddles(this, 2);
    ball1 = new Ball(this, 1);

}

public void update()
{
    if(w)
    {
        paddle1.move(true);
    }
    if(s)
    {
        paddle1.move(false);
    }
    if(up)
    {
        paddle2.move(true);
    }
    if(down)
    {
        paddle2.move(false);
    }

}
public void render(Graphics2D page) 
{
    page.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    page.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    page.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    if(gameStart == 0)
    {
        page.setFont(new Font("3 by 5 Regular", 1, 50));
        page.drawString("PONG 2.0", width / 2 - 50, 50);
    }
    else if(gameStart == 1)
    {
        page.setFont(new Font("3 by 5 Regular", 1, 50));
        page.drawString("GAME PAUSED", width / 2 - 120, height / 2);



    }
    else if(gameStart == 2)
    {
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        page.drawLine(width / 2, 5, width / 2, height);

        page.setFont(new Font("3 by 5 Regular", 1, 100));
        page.drawString(Integer.toString(0), width / 3, 75);
        page.drawString(Integer.toString(0), width / 3 * 2 - 60, 75);


        paddle1.render(page);
        paddle2.render(page);
        ball1.render(page);
    }


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    if(gameStart == 2)
    {
        update();
    }

    renderer.repaint();
    update();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    pong = new Pong();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
{
    int source = event.getKeyCode();
    if(source == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        w = true;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        s = true;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        up = true;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        down = true;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        gameStart = 2;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)  !!!!!!!!!!
    {
        gameStart = 1;
        if(source == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) 
{
    int source = event.getKeyCode();
    if(source == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        w = false;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        s = false;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        up = false;
    }
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        down = false;
    }

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) 
{


}
```

}

With this code it exits on the first press but I want it to exit on the second press. Thank you.

Comment: This code doesn't work as the jvm won't stop when in your keyPressed Method and wait for you to hit ESC a second time. :-) You could add a state-variable and check and set it when the ESC-key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use a variable to know if it is the first or second use of 
*Escape*, say

```
boolean escapeHit = false;
```

Then just use it

```
else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        gameStart = 1;

        // second escape key
        if(escapeHit){
          System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
          // first escape key  
          // display pause menu or whatever..
          escapeHit = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your variable to 1 (which I assume brings up the pause menu?) but your second `if` still passes and thus the program exits.

Try something like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
{
    ...
    else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        if(gameStart!=1) 
        {
            gameStart = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```